# Is it possible to print a string from C++ with Javascript using emscripten?

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

How can I pass a `char*` or `std::string` into an externally defined Javascript function using emscripten?

Currently, when I pass a `char*` into my externally defined Javascript, a number is printed instead of the string (pointers?).

Here is the code I am using:

mylib.js

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {  
    my_js: function(s) {  
        Module.print(s);
        console.log(s);
        document.getElementById('voronoi').innerHTML = s;
    },
 });
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char* myString = (char*) malloc(10);
    strncpy(myString, "SOMETHING", 10);
    my_js(myString);
    free(myString);
    return 0;
}
```

Result printed to the console when running `node ./a.out.js`:

`5260128`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with emscripten, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12359433/73681) to another question seems to use
 `Pointer_stringify("...")` to convert from C strings.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is using [embind](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html#using-val-to-transliterate-javascript-to-c).

You can refer my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38813881/2174271) for more details.