# Where should I defined emscripten extern functions in JS?

Tags: javascript, emscripten, asm.js

Suppose I have function `x` in C++ defined as:

```
extern "C" void x();
```

and I implement it in JS in global context

```
function _x() { console.log('x called'); }
```

`_x` is defined in asm compiled js file, which is getting invoked and not my implementation. What am I doing wrong?

I'm getting this warning while linking:

```
warning: unresolved symbol: x
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Uncaught abort() at Error
at jsStackTrace (http://localhost/module.js:978:13)
at stackTrace (http://localhost/module.js:995:22)
at abort (http://localhost/module.js:71106:25)
at _x (http://localhost/module.js:5829:46)
at Array._x__wrapper (http://localhost/module.js:68595:41)
at Object.dynCall_vi (http://localhost/module.js:68442:36)
at invoke_vi (http://localhost/module.js:7017:25)
at _LoadFile (http://localhost/module.js:7573:6)
at asm._LoadFile (http://localhost/module.js:69219:25)
at eval (eval at cwrap (http://localhost/module.js:554:17), <anonymous>:6:26)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your aim / use case is?

Comment: Communication between emscripten compiled JS to normal JS (http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#implement-a-c-api-in-javascript)

Comment: Passing a string between emscripten compiled JS to normal JS (http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#implement-a-c-api-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

As described at [Implement a C API in Javascript](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#implement-a-c-api-in-javascript), you define a library by having a Javascript file that calls `mergeInto` to merge an object with your Javascript functions into `LibraryManager.library`. You then compile with the `--js-library` option to pass in the location of your library.

For example, you can have Javascript file with your library of a single function

```
// In library.js
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
  x: function() {
    alert('hi');
  },
});
```

a main C++ file that calls this function

```
// in librarytest.cc
extern "C" void x();

int main()
{
  x();
  return 0;
}
```

and compile to HTML and Javascript with

```
em++ librarytest.cc --js-library library.js -o librarytest.html
```

then you load `librarytest.html` in a browser, it will show an alert box with `hi`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a string from C++ to Javascript, you don't have to go the route of [Implement a C API in Javascript](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#implement-a-c-api-in-javascript). Instead, you can use the [EM_ASM* macros](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#calling-javascript-from-c-c) to directly inline the Javascript. This can then call out to Javascript functions you have defined, and pass their values.

Also, to pass a string, you need to make sure you pass a C-style string, and then use the Emscripten-supplied `Pointer_stringify` Javascript function on the result:

```
#include <string>

#include <emscripten.h>

int main()
{
  std::string myString("This is a string in C++");

  EM_ASM_ARGS({
    console.log(Pointer_stringify($0));
  }, myString.c_str());

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it with "Implement a C API in Javascript"? because that is more readable.